# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray', Counter rows

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, counter

I'm trying to view the frequency of the elements in a 2d array as in the code:

```
a = np.array([22,33,22,55])
b = np.array([66,77,66,99])

x = np.column_stack((a,b))

print(collections.Counter(x))
```

Expected result: ({(22, 66): 2, (33, 77): 1, (55, 99): 1})

But I get:

```
 File "/Users/Documents/dos.py", line 8, in <module>
     print(collections.Counter(x))
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 552, in __init__
     self.update(iterable, **kwds)
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 637, in update
     _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of elements across all the sublists?

Comment: No, across the rows

Comment: What's your expected output? Please edit that into your original post.

Comment: `Counter` is using a python `dict` to collect the items it's counting.  A numpy array, or row of an array can't be used a `dict` `key`.  Turning that array into a list of tuples should work in `Counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [146]: a = np.array([22,33,22,55])
     ...: b = np.array([66,77,66,99])
     ...: 
     ...: x = np.column_stack((a,b))
     ...: 
In [147]: x
Out[147]: 
array([[22, 66],
       [33, 77],
       [22, 66],
       [55, 99]])
In [148]: from collections import Counter
```

Create a list of tuples:  (tuples are hashable)

```
In [149]: xl = [tuple(row) for row in x]
In [150]: xl
Out[150]: [(22, 66), (33, 77), (22, 66), (55, 99)]
```

Now Counter works:

```
In [151]: Counter(xl)
Out[151]: Counter({(22, 66): 2, (33, 77): 1, (55, 99): 1})
```

`numpys` own `unique` also works

```
In [154]: np.unique(x, axis=0, return_counts=True)
Out[154]: 
(array([[22, 66],
        [33, 77],
        [55, 99]]),
 array([2, 1, 1]))
```